# How to fix the error "Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Statement"?

Tags: java, drjava

1 error found:

> File: C:\Users\little\OneDrive\lab_2.java  [line: 70]
>   Error: Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Statement

I am new to drjava. What wrong with my program?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class lab_2 { 
  public static void main (String[]args){
   int choice;
    Scanner myscan=new Scanner(Systemin);
    boolean didntquit=true;

   while("didntquit") 
      //show menu
      System.out.println("Please choose an option");
      System.out.println("1)Quadratic Function");
      System.out.println("2)Distance Formula");
      System.out.println("3)Even or Odd");
      System.out.println("4)Factorial");
      System.out.println("5)Fibonacci");
      System.out.println("6)display the digits (in reverse order) of an integer");
      System.out.println("7)Quit Program");

         //get the option

        choice=myscan.nextInt();

        //do the option

        if (choice=7)
          didntquit=false;

        //quitint the program ^^^^

        else if (choice=1){
          int a;
          int b;
          int c;
          System.out.println("what is a ?");
          a=myscan.next ;
         System.out.println("what is b ?");
         b=myscan.next ;
         System.out.println("what is c ?");
         c=myscan.next ;
       double outa =(b + Math.sqrt((b*b)-4*a*c))/(2*a);
       double outa =(b - Math.sqrt((b*b)-4*a*c))/(2*a);   
       }
          //quadratic formula ^^^^

        else if(choice=2){
          System.out.println("What is the x cordinate of the first point?");
          int x1 = myscan.nextInt();
          int x2 = myscan.nextInt();
          int y1 = myscan.nextInt();
          int y2 = myscan.nextInt();
           double dist = Math.sqrt((x2-x1)*2)+((y2-y1)*2);  
        }
             else if (choice=3){
               int x;
                System.out.println("Enter an integer to check if it is even           or odd");
               Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
               x =in.nextInt();

               if (x%2==0)
                System.out.println("You entered an even number");
               else
                 System.out.println("You entered an odd number");
       }
             else if (choice=4){
               Scanner scanner = new Scanner(Systemin);
               System.out.println("Enter the number");

               int num =Scanner.nextInt();
                int factorial = fact(num);
               System.out.println("factorial of entered number is: "+factorial);  

             }
             static int fact(int n)
             {
               int output;
               if(n==1)
                 return 1;

               output=fact(n-1)*n;
               return output;
             }
     }
```

I need help figuring out what's wrong with this code. I made it so it might not be exactly easy to read, as I'm a beginner.

Comment: Your indentation is rather haphazard, and is difficult to see if it is correct. I would expect your `while()` needs to have an opening brace `while() {` to start with. Maybe tidy up  the indentation (in particular from `//get the option` which appears to be incorrectly indented) and then see where a brace is missing?

Comment: Several `if` statements are wrong too: you need `==` instead of `=` to test for equality (but they are not the cause of the compilation error, @halfer already gave that).

Comment: I wonder if `while("didntquit")` should be `while(didntquit)` - if it's boolean then the quotes should not be necessary. Are you using core Java or this is a special version? I have not heard of drjava.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `}` at the end of the `main` method.

I can see a number of other problems in your code, many of them obscured by incorrect indentation.  DRJava can fix the indentation in your code automatically; e.g. using the `IndentFiles` utility described [here](http://www.drjava.org/docs/user/apc.html).  I strongly recommend that you use it ... and then look at the code to see what I am talking about.

Hint: after `IndentFiles`, the indentation will look incorrect, but it will reflect what your code (as written) is actually saying.